# Symfony2 - Form processing with $_GET

Tags: php, forms, symfony

It's a simply problem but, I have question about Form process (`isValid()` & `GetData()`) with **`$_GET`** request not a `$_POST` request.

```php
$form->isValid() // return false everytime !
$form->getData() // return NULL everytime too
```

So I deduced that this was the method `$_GET` which prevents normal process of form validation.
Someone has already had this problem ??

*More infos :* I've a class form name LargeSearchType.php without entity relation. Just a search engine form with many select,checkbox... My controller use Symfony2 standard (documentation) process form. (http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/forms.html#gerer-la-soumission-des-formulaires)

Comment: Did you set `->setMethod('GET')` during creating form?

Comment: Thx for your response ! I've again looked symfony doc and find your solution. I forgot to specify ->setMethod('GET') because my twig not render form correctly... <form method="GET" action=".." ...> instead of form_start(form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the method of the form to `GET`:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
             ->setMethod('GET')
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form

Comment: Thx for your response. I found the solution with Symfony2 doc as you.